# Why are the domains of $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-2}}$ and $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-2}}$ different?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

Consider the following functions
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-2}} \qquad g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-2}}$$
It is easy to check that, $D_f=(-\infty,1]\cup(2,\infty)$ and $D_g=(2,\infty)$.

I do not have a good the reason why the domain is different for $f$ and $g$. It is seems the functions are the same. Any idea ?

Comment: $f=g$ on $D_g$ as $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ holds only for $a,b\geq 0$.

Comment: The functions are not the same.  $\frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ is not the same thing as $\sqrt {\frac ab}$.  They'll take the same value if $a,b$ are both positive, and are both undefined if one of $a,b$ is negative but the other is positive.  But if both $a,b$ are negative they are very different expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions for the domain of $f(x)$ are:
$$\frac{x-1}{x-2}\geq 0\,\, \text{and}\,\, x-2\neq0$$
Whereas the conditions for the domain of $g(x)$ are:
$$x-1\geq0\,\, \text{,}\,\, x-2\geq0\,\, \text{and}\,\, x-2\neq0
$$

Answer (score 4):

For $f$, if both $x-1$ and $x-2$ are negative (that is, $x \in (- \infty, 1)$), the quotient cancels out the signs and is a possitive number, yielding a well-defined square root.

For $g$ however, this cancelling can not take place since the square roots are taken first, and if either of $x-1$ and $x-2$ is negative, the square root cannot be well-defined, so $g(x)$ can't be either.